# Issue populating mongoose models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two models, Pokemon and Attacks. The Pokemon model has an array of moves as strings, which I would like to populate with the Attacks collection using the Attack name as the key.

**Pokemon Model**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var PokemonSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  types: [{
    type: String,
    required: true
  }],
  abilities: [{
    type: String,
    required: true
  }],
  stats: [{
    type: Number,
    required: true
  }],
  moves: [{
    type: String,
    ref: 'Attack'
  }]
});

var Pokemon = mongoose.model("Pokemon", PokemonSchema);

module.exports = Pokemon;
```

**Attack Model**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var AttackSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  power: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  accuracy: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  damage_class: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  target: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

var Attack = mongoose.model("Attack", AttackSchema);

module.exports = Attack;
```

**Populate Code**

```
await Pokemon.find({}).populate({path: "moves"}).then((err, docs) => {
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(docs[0].moves[0].power)
    })
```

Running this gives me an error so long the console seems to be unable to log the whole thing. Is the issue that the moves attribute in the pokemon model isn't an object_id? The API I was using to get this data only gave me the names of the attacks and not their respective id's.

Comment: You need to reference the `_id` value for `populate` to work.  `Pokemon.moves` needs to be an array of `ObjectId` for it to work. Would you like an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Model.poplate` to work you need to reference the `_id` field as per the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). Make these changes:

```js
var PokemonSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  //..
  //..
  moves: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Attack'
  }]
});
```

You need to manually add the `Attack._id` of each `Attack` you want referenced in the `Pokemon`. It will not happen automatically. Methods such as `findByIdAndUpdate` or `findOneAndUpdate` will help you do that.

Then when you search:

```js
try{
   const docs = await Pokemon.find({}).populate({path: "moves"});
}catch(err){
   console.log(err);
}
```